# How do I permanantly disable zoom feature when taking screenshots/screencapture (cmd+shift+4)?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

Recently made a jump to Mountain Lion and it appears Apple added a feature to the screenshot function (cmd+shift+4) that zooms in when it is a small screenshot. It's a pain and I want to disable it permanently. Is there any way I can do this?

Example screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please fix the sloppy spelling of the question, and add what OS version you're using, I.e. 10.6? 10.7? 10.8?

Comment: Are you using a Retina MacBook Pro? From the looks of that screenshot, you likely are. It's probable that the screenshot isn't actually "zoomed", it's just appearing larger than normal when you open it up, due to some retina scaling weirdness. Certainly on my non-retina 10.8 machine, the screenshot function works as it always has.

Comment: @gosmond feel free to suggest edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screengrab taken on the “normal” unscaled display has the correct pixel dimensions along with a DPI (Dots per inch) of 72, which has been the standard DPI on Macs for a very long time. The screengrab taken on the Retina display, however, is much larger, with a proportionately higher DPI. This makes sense, due to the way OS X handles scaling on the Retina display.
So, even though the image appears “normal” size on a Retina screen, it’s actually being rendered at the higher DPI / larger size and scaled down. When the OS X screencapture utility is used to take a screen grab, it captures the image at the higher DPI and resolution. And when that image is uploaded to be viewed on the web, it is way too big.

Seems the solution is http://www.retinacapture.com/